# HtmlUnit and cookies

Tags: java, cookies, htmlunit

When I open the same site with Google Chrome on one side and HtmlUnit.WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME) on the other, I do not see the same cookies on both sides. Cookies are checked here with Google-Chrome-Dev. Nine cookies vs four cookies for the same site.

The site is [linckx.odoo.com](https://linckx.odoo.com/).

Is there something missing in my HtmlUnit code?

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        
CookieManager cookieManager = webClient.getCookieManager();

final HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage(url + "/en_US/web/login");
```

[image: HtmlUnit]

[image: Google Chrome]

Comment: Is this site public? Any chance to reproduce?

Comment: https://linckx.odoo.com/

Answer (score 0):

If i access the page https://linckx.odoo.com/en_US/web/login
with a new browser (remove all cookies before) i get

[image]

nothing more.
Maybe the differences are from other request you did in your browser before.

new WebClient() in HtmlUnit is like starting a Browser with a complete new profile (all caches are empty, no cookies).